# Swift: filter protocol array by comparing types

Tags: xcode, swift

(first post)

usually im able to find answers here or elsewhere but no luck this time =(

Question: in Swift, how do you filter an array that is of a protocol type by an implementing type supplied as a function parameter?

```
protocol Aprotocol {
   var number:Int { get set }
}

class Aclass: Aprotocol {
    var number = 1
}

class AnotherClass: Aprotocol {
    var number = 1
}

var array:[Aprotocol] = [ Aclass(), AnotherClass(), Aclass() ]

func foo (parameter:Aprotocol) -> Int {
    return array.filter({ /* p in p.self == parameter.self  */ }).count
}

var bar:Aprotocol = // Aclass() or AnotherClass()

var result:Int = foo(bar) // should return 2 or 1, depending on bar type
```

maybe this is not the right approach at all?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I think you want:

```
return array.filter { (element: Aprotocol) -> Bool in
    element.dynamicType == parameter.dynamicType
}.count
```

But I recommend this, which does the same, but without the useless instance of `Aclass()` which is passed in the answer on the top. Also this way is faster:

```
func foo <T: Aprotocol>(type: T.Type) -> Int {
    return array.filter { (element: Aprotocol) -> Bool in
        element.dynamicType == type
    }.count
}

var result:Int = foo(Aclass)
```

The `dynamicType` will return the Type of an instance

Answer (score 0):

Very easy:

```
return array.filter({ parameter.number == $0.number }).count
```

Comment: pretend for a moment that the value of the property could not help, you had to do the evaluation by comparing types (edited example to be more clear)

Comment: @MattiasLundblad I posted another one which I think is what you wanted ;)

Answer (score 0):

Kametrixoms solution works (if you use "is T" instead of "== type") but in my case, since i didnt know which implementing class was going to call it, had to go with this solution:

```
protocol Aprotocol: AnyObject {
    var number:Int { get set }
}

class func foo(parameter: AnyObject) -> Int {    
    return array.filter ({ (element: Aprotocol) -> Bool in
    object_getClassName(element) == object_getClassName(parameter)
  }).count
}
```